# google analytics GA4 API integration in RAILS 5.2 using google-apis-analyticsdata_v1beta gem library

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm getting an error in request invalid

```
`gem 'google-apis-analyticsdata_v1beta', '~> 0.21.0'
```

```
# Load the client
require "google/apis/analyticsdata_v1beta"
require 'googleauth'
namespace :google_analytics do
    desc 'cron job for syncing google analytics services'
    task :analytics => [:environment] do
        begin
          client = Google::Apis::AnalyticsdataV1beta::AnalyticsDataService.new
          credentials = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(json_key_io: IO.new(IO.sysopen('credentials.json')))
          credentials.scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
          client.authorization = credentials.fetch_access_token!({})["access_token"]

          body = {
          "requests": [
            {
              "date_ranges": [
                {
                  "start_date": "7daysAgo",
                  "end_date": "today"
                }
              ],
              "dimensions": [
                {
                  "name": "pageTitle"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
          request = Google::Apis::AnalyticsdataV1beta::BatchRunReportsRequest.new(body)
          property_id = '3384098947333'
          property = "properties/#{property_id}"
          results = client.batch_property_run_reports(property, request)
          
           pp results
        rescue => exception
          puts "Exception : Error"
          puts exception.message
          puts "------------------------------"
        end
    end
end
```

i have tried gem 'google-apis-analyticsdata_v1beta' which help us to send API along with authorisation

I have created custom user field with custom event so i can get that data back for showing report in my so using API for the same but getting error in request, what exactly syntax for the same not sure, lack of documentation won't be able to do it well, if anyone help that would be great

creating job so that will run every periodically and fetch data to my app from google analytics